# How to time tests with pytest?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, pytest

How can I display the amount of time taken for each test executed by pytest?

I've investigated pytest-timeout, pytest-timeit, and pytest-benchmark.  pytest-benchmark is closest, but requires wrapping every test manually.

The most pressing need is to figure out why testing under Py 3.x takes almost twice as long as Py 2.7. There are 231 top-level tests in the package I want to test (as identified by pytest), so wrapping all of these is not trivial.

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884404/printing-test-execution-times-and-pinning-down-slow-tests-with-py-test

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#profiling-test-execution-duration

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by autouse fixture and `pytest_runtest_makereport`

Add below code to your root `conftest.py`. It would print out test duration for every test.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def testcase_result(request):
    print("Test '{}' STARTED".format(request.node.nodeid))
    def fin():
        print("Test '{}' COMPLETED".format(request.node.nodeid))
        print("Test '{}' DURATION={}".format(request.node.nodeid,request.node.rep_call.duration))
    request.addfinalizer(fin)


@pytest.mark.tryfirst
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call, __multicall__):
    rep = __multicall__.execute()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep
```

Hope it would help you !

Comment: This is a fine response and very educational. However, I think the better answer is provided in the question that others referenced re: --durations=0 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884404/printing-test-execution-times-and-pinning-down-slow-tests-with-py-test).