# Can I print the cumulative time per pytest fixture?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-fixtures

I'm currently struggling with a test suite that is slower than I would like it to be. I want to figure out which part is the most promising to work on.

One technique I know is [`--durations`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27899853/562769), but that is not super helpful in my case.

I have tons of fixtures and I would like to improve the most critical ones.

Is there a way to measure the time spent per fixture (cumulative) over the whole test suite and print that?

Comment: It's a Django application and many tests use the `db` fixture. That is just a side-comment and not the real question - but it that gives somebody ideas what I should look at, I'd be happy to hear them :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pytest_fixture_setup` hook in `conftest.py`. This will print the run time for each fixture and the cumulative time

```
import time

total = 0
groups = {}


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_fixture_setup(fixturedef, request):
    start = time.time()
    yield
    end = time.time()

    global total, groups
    name = fixturedef.argname
    duration = round(end - start)
    total += duration
    groups[name] = groups.get(name, 0) + duration

    print(f'{name}: {duration}')
    print(f'cumulative: {total}')
```

**Edit using `xdist`:**

When using `xdist` each worker is running in a different process, which makes the variables belong to different sessions. To share them you can write the data to files from `pytest_sessionfinish` of each worker and sum them in the global `pytest_sessionfinish`

```
total = 0
groups = {}


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_fixture_setup(fixturedef, request):
    start = time.time()
    yield
    end = time.time()

    global total, groups
    name = fixturedef.argname
    duration = round(end - start)
    total += duration
    groups[name] = groups.get(name, 0) + duration


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    if hasattr(session.config, 'workerinput'):
        groups['cumulative'] = total
        path = f'{os.path.join("data", session.config.workerinput["workerid"])}.json'
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
        with open(path, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(groups, file)
    else:
        counter = Counter()
        for filename in os.listdir('data'):
            with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data', filename)) as file:
                counter += json.load(file)
        print(counter)
```

Comment: Why do you multiply by 1000?

Comment: @MartinThoma You don't really need it, I edited the code.

Comment: I fixed a bug. Do you know how to do it so that it groups the time by fixture? So cummulative over the test, but splitting by fixture

Comment: Is `fixturedef.argname` the name of the fixture?

Comment: @MartinThoma You can keep track with a dictionary based on the fixture name (`fixturedef.argname`).

Comment: It seems not to be exceuted at all as I see no messages. Might pytest-xdist interfere?

Comment: @MartinThoma Probably, I added a solution.